# How can I give my Samsung Galaxy S2, with ICS, a name?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth

When my Samsung Galaxy S2 ran on Gingerbread I had a unique Bluetooth name set on it to differentiate from members of my family when I wanted to receive files by Bluetooth from their devices. However, since my upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich I cannot see how to give my phone a name so that others searching for my phone by Bluetooth can find mine without others having switch theirs off to distingiush mine as the only one with its Bluetooth switched on. Can anybody help with this? Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: I have a "Rename Phone" option on my Galaxy Nexus under the overflow menu (the 3 little dots) of the Bluetooth settings page. Do you have that on your SGS2's settings?

Answer (score 2):

considering you're running the Samsung stock ICS

go to "Settings" then "Bluetooth", turn your Bluetooth on, click the menu button (the one left of the Home button) and click "Device name". then edit your device name.